# Conversion issue - Python?

Tags: python, string, debugging, pandas

I have been debugging my script and I have narrowed down my issue to a few lines of code that I believe to be causing my problem.  I'm reading in data from 3 csv files, extracting data from a sproc in SQL Server, and exporting the data from both to an excel file to draw cmparisons.  The problem I'm getting is my source file is producing duplicates (one row from each source file).  I put print statements in the following data to see whats going on.

```
#convert district codes to strings
if dfyearfound:
    df2['district_code']=df2['district_code'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    print df2['district_code'][df2.index[0]]
    df2['district_type_code']=df2['district_type_code'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    print df2['district_type_code'][df2.index[0]]
if teacheryearfound:
    teacherframe['district_code']=teacherframe['district_code'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    print teacherframe['district_code'][teacherframe.index[0]]
    teacherframe['district_type_code']=teacherframe['district_type_code'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    print teacherframe['district_type_code'][teacherframe.index[0]]
if financialyearfound:
    financialframe['district_code']=financialframe['district_code'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    print financialframe['district_code'][financialframe.index[0]]
    financialframe['district_type_code']=financialframe['district_type_code'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    print financialframe['district_type_code'][financialframe.index[0]]
```

The print statement gives me the following output: 1, 1, 1, 3.0, 0012, 1

All the dist_codes should be of length 4 and they vary in the source file from 1 digit to 4 digits.  In the database they are all 4 digits (example: 0001, 0012).  The district type is 1 or 2 digits, all being 2 in the database (example: 01, 03).  I'm not sure why the above string conversion is not working.  I was going to write a function to format the district_code and district_type_code but I don't want to hard code the length and the function I wrote I could not get to work:

```
#function for formating district codes
def formatDistrictCodes(code):

    dist=code
    dist.zfill(4)

    return dist


formatDistrictCodes(districtformat)
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your question. Also, what is that `apply` method?

Comment: `lambda x: str(x)`, may as well just pass `str`.

Comment: Are you using `pandas`? If so please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Try return dist.zfill(4). zfill does not change the original string but returns a new padded string.

Comment: `pandas` usually infers types from `csv` files. So your beautiful strings `0001`, `0002` are converted to ints.

Comment: 3.0 is a float so if pandas is inferring an int or float I need to convert it to a string.  Further down in the script I'm conctenating district_code and district_type which are producing three different values for my uniqe key (012396, 1.02396, 12396).  The correct key would be 012396.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the meat of your problem is this:

> All the dist_codes should be of length 4 and they vary in the source
>   file from 1 digit to 4 digits. In the database they are all 4 digits
>   (example: 0001, 0012). The district type is 1 or 2 digits, all being 2
>   in the database (example: 01, 03).

In Python, any number that begins with `0` is an octal:

```
>>> 016
14
```

So what you really want is to take a digit, and prepend a series of zeros to is for a fixed length of 4, and then make sure its a string.

```
>>> str(1).zfill(4)
'0001'
```

In your code, this would be:

```
str(df2['district_code']).zfill(4)
```

Note that this won't *enforce* the length. It will just make sure the minimum length is 4. For all values that are more than 4 digits, the above has no effect.